# Remove Lync 2010 Standard

Tags: lync

I am trying to remove my single server Lync standard install via the Topology Builder.

By going in to my site -> Standard Edition Front End Servers -> Delete, i get the error `A published pool hosting Central Management Service can not be removed`

I cant remove the server from the topology so cant run the deployment wizard which will remove the role from the server.

As an edit from a post, I have now done the following:

1. Lync Control Panel -> Deleted all the Lync users from Lync  ->
   commit all
2. Get-CsConferenceDirectory | Remove-CsConferenceDirectory
3. Get-CsExUmContact -Filter {RegistrarPool -eq "hqslc1.domain.local"}
   | Remove-CsExUmContact
4. Get-CsRgsWorkflow -Identity:Service:ApplicationServer:hqslc1.domain.local | Remove-CsRgsWorkflow
5. Get-CsDialInConferencingAccessNumber | where {$_.Pool -eq "hqslc1.domain.local"} |
   Remove-CsDialInConferencingAccessNumber
6. Get-CsCommonAreaPhone -Filter {RegistrarPool -eq "hqslc1.domain.local"} | Remove-CsCommonAreaPhone
7. Get-CsCallParkOrbit followed by Remove-CsCallParkOrbit -Identity "Home Park Orbit"
8. Lync Control panel -> Voice Features -> Unassigned Number, delete, commit all
9. Lync Control Panel -> Voice Routing > Route -> Edit -> Select all -> Delete -> Commit all

Despite the above, I still cannot remove the server or when running the Remove Deployment wizard no changes are made.

[image: error]

Comment: This guy ran into the same thing and has detailed instructions per MS support...find the same error screenshot and follow along: http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2011/01/step-by-step-instructions-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the pool created before you can run the Topology Builder.

Which is Phase 3 & 4 of the Decommissioning a Deployment guide for Lync:

[image]

The following Technet article has all the steps to follow to decomm. your Lync installation, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg195815%28v=ocs.14%29.aspx).

Comment: many thanks, have gone through that and listed the commands thus far, still pulling my hair out :)

Comment: Your steps, along with the tip from @TheCleaner and link http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2011/01/step-by-step-instructions-for.html sorted me out